# Caching custom block

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

im trying to cache a custom block from my module but is not working, is something wrong with my code?

```
 $cacheId = 'my_cache_id';
if (false !== ($data = Mage::app()->getCache()->load($cacheId))) {
    $data = unserialize($data);

    return $data;
} else {
       $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                            ->addMinimalPrice()
                            ->addTaxPercents()
                            ->addStoreFilter()
                            ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc');

        // CategoryFilter
        $collection = $this->categoryFilter($collection);

        // getNumProduct
       $collection->setPageSize($this->getWidgetCfg('limit'));
        Mage::app()->getCache()->save(serialize($collection), $cacheId);
        return Mage::app()->getCache()->load($cacheId); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is a little bit messed up with serialization :)

look into this

```
    // getNumProduct
   $collection->setPageSize($this->getWidgetCfg('limit'));
    Mage::app()->getCache()->save(serialize($collection), $cacheId);
    return Mage::app()->getCache()->load($cacheId);
```

you are returning serialized object from cache.

simply return $collection, this will even improve initial performance